# Using [DisallowNull] vs non-nullable reference type

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I am learning about the ins-and-outs of nullable reference types in C# 8.0

Whilst reading [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/) about nullable reference types, I was left a bit puzzled by the following example.

```
public static HandleMethods
{
    public static void DisposeAndClear([DisallowNull] ref MyHandle? handle)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The author shows how a `[DisallowNull]` attribute can be used in this case. However, my query is why would you need the attribute here at all? Is this code not the same?

```
public static HandleMethods
{
    public static void DisposeAndClear(ref MyHandle handle)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

By removing the attribute, and the `?` at the end of `MyHandle`, would this be a like-for-like alternative?

EDIT:

Thanks to UnholySheep, I believe I understand this now.

```
public static void DisposeAndClear([DisallowNull] ref MyHandle? handle)
{
    handle = null;
}
```

When calling this version of the function, `handle` cannot be null going in. However, it could be set to null inside the function, so when the function returns, anything using `handle` needs to check whether `handle` is null.

Comment: If I understand the relevant section of that blog post correctly the body of the method does at some point set `handle = null`, which is not allowed with the second version

Comment: Ah, thanks - I think I've figured it out now, based on your comment. The value `handle` cannot be passed as a null, but after the function returns, `handle` could be set to null. Right, got it, thanks. If you move your comment to an answer, I will accept that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments
The important part of the blog post is the following

> Typical use for this API is that we have a non-null instance that we
> pass by reference, but when it is cleared, the reference is null

This means that the method accepts a non-`null` object but at some point in the method `handle` will be set to `null`
As setting `handle` to `null` is not allowed in the version which takes a non-nullable reference as parameter (`ref MyHandle handle`) the other version has to be used